# Reassign variables to elements of list

Tags: r, assign

I have a list of objects in R on which I perform different actions using `lapply`. However in the next step I would like to apply functions only to certain elements of the list. Therefore I would like to split the list into the *original variables* again. Is there a command in R for this? Is it even possible, or do I have to create new variables each time I want to do this?
See the following example to make clear what I mean:

```
# 3 vectors:
test1 <- 1:3
test2 <- 2:6
test3 <- 8:9

# list l:
l <- list(test1,test2,test3)

# add 3 to each element of the list:
l <- lapply(l, function(x) x+3)

# In effect, list l contains modified versions of the three test vectors
```

**Question**: How can I assign those modifications to the original variables again? I do not want to do:

```
test1 <- l[[1]]
test2 <- l[[2]]
test3 <- l[[3]]
# etc.
```

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: You can do `list2env(lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "test[1-3]")), "+", 3), globalenv())` for the `lapply()` call then test1, 2, and 3 are all updated.  Although, you should really keep everything in the list and not clutter the global environment.

Comment: Thanks for the correct but very short reply. Maybe someone can explain to me what is behind this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more intuitive approach, assuming you're new to R, might be to use a for loop.  I do think that Richard Scriven's approach is better.  It is at least more concise.

```
for(i in seq(1, length(l))){
    name <- paste0("test",i)
    assign(name, l[[i]] + 3)
}
```

That all being said, your ultimate goal is a bit dubious. I would recommend that you save the results in a list or matrix, especially if you are new to R. By including all the results in a list or matrix you can continue to use functions like lapply and sapply to manipulate your results.

Loosely speaking Richard Scriven's approach in the comments is converting each element of your list into an object and then passing these objects to the enclosing environment which is the global environment in this case.  He could have passed the objects to any environment.  For example try,

```
e <- new.env()
list2env(lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "test[1-3]")), "+", 3), e)
```

Notice that `test1`, `test2` and `test3` are now in environment `e`.  Try `e$test1` or `ls(e)`.  Going deeper in to the parenthesis, the call to `ls` uses simple regular expressions to tell `mget` the names of the objects to look for.  For more, take a look at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html.

Comment: thanks, this is what I was looking for. Ok but 1 little follow-up question. If I keep all the variables in a list instead and assuming I want to apply certain functions just to some of them (that means I cannot use `lapply`), how can this be done? As I pointed out using `l[[index]]` is not so good in this case, because I don't remember which variable I put at `index` usually. So to say the variable names are lost by using a list. How to handle this?

Comment: When using R it is important to remember that `lists` and `data.frames` are very similar, read this http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html.  So it is possible to name the components of a `list`, just like it is possible to names variables in a `data.frame`.  In your case I would do this with `names(l) <- ls(pattern = "test*")`.  Now you can refer to the components of the list as `l[[test1]]` or `l$test1`. HTH