# How to remember which variables are in a list

Tags: r, list

I have a huge list in which I put different variables in order to apply the same function to all of them.

In a next step I want to apply specific functions to specific elements of the list, i.e. all functions used vary from element to element within the list.

How can I do this? My first idea was (see my other question, [Reassign variables to elements of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052585/reassign-variables-to-elements-of-list)) to split the list into the original variables again. This can be done.

But I was recommended to keep the items in the list instead. My questions is: How can I access each variable quickly by doing that? One idea would be to use the `names` attribute of the list in the beginning and fill it with a vector of the original variable names. However, by doing that it would be much longer later on to type `list["name_x"]` than just typing `name_x` assuming `name_x` is globally available.

What is the most efficient way to deal with my problem?

Comment: I don't understand your problem and would challenge that you have a problem at all.

Comment: If you're judging efficiency by least letters typed, then maybe you really do want to pull the elements out.  Lists are usually more convenient because you can apply the same function to every element at the same time, but if you have something distinct you need to do to each element, that's different.  Check out `list2env()`.

Comment: @Roland then you are challenging the wrong thing. I can make it very short: Sometimes I need to apply 1 function to 100 elements of a list (1 to 100, so I can use lapply), then I need to apply 100 different functions to the same 100 elements of the list (1 to 1 pairs, I cannot use lapply because the function/element pairs differ of each other). What is the best way of how to do it when the required structure of your data changes over time?

Comment: One more thing to add: I will try to reformulate the question later today to make it more clear. I think a lot of you must have faced this problem in the beginning of their R usage as well.

Comment: `l <- list(1, 2, 3); funs <- list(exp, sin, log); mapply(function(x, fun) fun(x), l, funs)`

Comment: @Roland ty, that's a powerful method when your list is kind of small i.e. you know which variable is at which index. But you must be careful with the order.
But thanks guys, I think with `list2env()`, the solution provided in my original thread and `mapply` I have a lot of solutions to work with. Now I must take the decision which is best for my case.

Comment: Hint: `list2env` is not the best solution. Don't clutter your global environment. Otherwise, you will regret that sooner or later.